# set the starting node for spreading a virus in a network

Tags: r, graph, igraph, complex-networks

I'm working on finding influential nodes in complex networks using R programming. I want to use degree centrality which means the number of neighbors a node has in a graph. I have a graph and the degree centrality of each node. Now I want to know how many nodes will be infected within a specified time when we start to spread the virus from each node. according to my studies I should use SIR(susceptible, infected, recovered) epidemic model which I found in "igraph" package, the problem is that I can't specify the starting node. It seems that this functions works based on SIR equations:

```
s'= -(beta)SI
I' = (beta)SI - (gamma)I
R' = (gamma)I
```

where beta is infection parameter and gamma is recovery parameter.
here is the igraph SIR code:

```
function (graph, beta, gamma, no.sim = 100) 
{
if (!is_igraph(graph)) {
    stop("Not a graph object")
}
beta <- as.numeric(beta)
gamma <- as.numeric(gamma)
no.sim <- as.integer(no.sim)
on.exit(.Call("R_igraph_finalizer", PACKAGE = "igraph"))
res <- .Call("R_igraph_sir", graph, beta, gamma, no.sim, 
    PACKAGE = "igraph")
class(res) <- "sir"
res
}
```

It seems that most of the work is being done in "R_igraph_sir" but I cant find such a function in that package.
Is there any way to set the starting node?

Comment: I think you'll find the code you're looking for in the .c implementation backing the R package here: https://github.com/igraph/igraph/blob/master/src/sir.c
You won't be able to change it without re-compiling the R-package

Comment: Wasted my edit, but there's one more remark: You would be looking at line 170 in the previously mentioned sir.c
Specifically you would have to set that initial infected to the node of your choice.

Comment: you may also want to look at the stochastic network models implemented in the `EpiModel` package. I haven't tried the package yet, but it does seem like can use set which nodes are initially infected (`status.vector`) and set network information such as degree distribution using `nwstats` arguments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like you'd like to have a SIR model where you are able to set the initially infected node by monkeypatching the existing R code. Since the R package is compiled from C code this might be tough depending on your programming experience and in general monkeypatching isn't recommended, if nothing else then because you will lose your code the minute you update your `igraph` package.

Instead you can relatively easily implement this yourself using the `igraph` package. Below is an untested implementation in python that should be easibly ported to R.

The first step infects any node in the graph adjacent to an infected node with a probability of `beta`

After infection stage any infected node can be removed from the graph with a probability of `gamma`

After the given number of timesteps you find the number of effected nodes as the size of the `infected_nodes` array. This won't count removed nodes, so if you want the total number of infected over the entire simulation you put in a counter that increments each time you infect a node

```
infected_nodes = []
# Set the infection rate
beta = 0.1
# Set the removal rate
gamma = 0.1
# Set how many timesteps you want to pass through
n_timesteps = 100
# Start from the node you have chosen using edge centrality
infected_nodes.append(chosen_node)
for _ in n_timesteps:
    # Infection stage
    for node in infected_nodes:
        for neighbor in igraph.neighborhood(graph, node):
            # random.random simply returns a number between [0,1)
            if random.random() < beta:
                infected_nodes.append(neighbor)
    # Removal stage
    infected_survivors = []
    for node in infected_nodes:
        if random.random() < gamma:
            graph = igraph.delete_vertices(graph, node)
        else:
            infected_survivors.append(node)
    infected_nodes = infected_survivors
```

Some aberdabeis:

- This assumes every node visits all their neighbors at each timestep. If you only want each node to be able to infect `n` neighbors per turn you will need to take a size `n` random sample of the neighbors instead of iterating over all of them.
- In the removal stage it is possible to remove newly infected nodes, meaning that there is a chance that a node will not have the opportunity to infect its neighbors. If this is not realistic in your case you will have to store newly infected nodes in a separate array and add them to the infected nodes at the beginning of the infection stage
- This will obviously be slower than C implementation provided by the R package